# Ugly Url with in single page Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have a `<div id="section1"> </div>` at the bottom of my page.
And I have a button I want this functionality in button

```
 $location.hash('section1');
 $anchorScroll();
```

It is working as I want but it is giving me ugly url all this is in single page than why my url is updating?

my expecting Url is :

```
/Order/BuildOrder
```

when page load I get this but when I click button screen took me to my anchor div with id='section1'

but now url change to `/Order/BuildOrder#!#section1`

How can I remove #!# as this is scrolling on a single page. href location is not changing

Comment: I have <div id='section1'> </div> somewhere at the bottom of my page

Comment: can i see you config code buddy?